# SCALA- get higher percentage of a value filtering keys

Tags: scala

here is my question:
I have a map with keys like regions and values a seq of characteristics of persons of this regions:

```
("Asia" -> [Person(region: "Asia", hair: "brown", eyes: "blue",....), Person(.......)
("America" -> [Person(region: "America", hair: "red", eyes: "brown",....), Person(.......)
```

i have to return which region has the higher percentage of blue eyed persons but i dont know how to access to the characteristics of each person. i can acces values like `grouped.count(_._2 == "blue")`. can someone help me? thanks in advance

Comment: i have to def a function to return the region (string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decompose your problem in multiple steps:

- compute the percentage of blue eyes for each region
- find the max

Which can actually be solved with a single method `maxBy` in Scala:

```scala
val population: Map[String, Seq[Person]] = ???

val (region, persons) = population
  .maxBy { case (region, persons) =>
    persons.count(_.eyes == "blue") / persons.size
  }
```

*Consider using `maxByOption` to be safer in case your map is empty*

See [https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#maxBy[B](f:A=%3EB)(implicitcmp:scala.math.Ordering[B]):A](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#maxBy%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB)(implicitcmp:scala.math.Ordering%5BB%5D):A)

Comment: Thanks so much! and how can i get that string region?

Comment: all i had at first was a Seq with a bunch of Persons characteristics and ive done a groupby region. is that ok?

Comment: Hi! i tried your solution but region returns nothing, i dont know how to solve it

Comment: @Kirk I don't understand what you mean by I get nothing. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6gpF8il3RfGomG3ot5gSug this prints the region with max percentage

Comment: def mostBlue(c: Seq[Person]): String = {
    val population = dataset.groupBy(_.eyes)
    val (region, persons) = population.maxBy { case (region, persons) => persons.count(_.eyes == "blue") / persons.size
  } //Im writing this code but i dont get that return. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Kirk that function you put in the comments doesn't actually return anything (returns `Unit`), you have put `region` in the last line to return it. I recommend going through a basic Scala tutorial to learn the basic syntax and semantics of the language, like how to define functions

Comment: i did. still nothing in return. Thanks so much for your response!